# Having issues in BATCH with files similarly named using commands such as FOR /F, FIND /C, etc

Tags: batch-file, pdf, for-loop, find

I have written a small program in Batch that takes a pair of PDFs along with a control file and zips them up to be sent off to another team within our company. I have recently expanded this program to handle additional types of PDFs but the additional types are similarly named to the preexisting causing issues with my program.

Below is my code:

```
:ZIPPAIRS
::Zips pairs -- checks for pairs first using filelist.txt
ECHO [INFO] Checking for pairs, if a pair exists, zipping it up >> %LOG%
ECHO.
ECHO Zipping all pairs from your PDFCOMPARE folder...
ECHO.
CD %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN (filelist.txt) DO (
        SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
        CD %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE
        SET COMPAREZIPS="dir /b "%%i*.pdf" | find /c "%%i" "
        FOR /F %%j IN (' !COMPAREZIPS! ') DO SET X=%%j
        IF !X! EQU 2 (
                ECHO [INFO] Zipping %%i PDF's and control_file.xml >> %LOG%
                ECHO Zipping %%i PDF's and control_file.xml...
                %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\7-ZIP\7z a %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%i.zip %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%i*.* %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPAREDOWNLOADED\control_file.xml
                ECHO.
                ECHO [INFO] Moving %%i PDF's >> %LOG%
                ECHO Moving %%i PDF's
                ECHO.
                MOVE %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%i*.pdf %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\FINISHED
                MOVE %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%i*.zip %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\ZIPS
            )   ELSE (
                ECHO.
                ECHO.
                ECHO [WARN] This compare %%i does not have a matching pair >> %LOG%
                ECHO This compare %%i does not have a matching pair
                ECHO.
                ECHO.
            )
SET i=""
SET j=""
SET X=""
ENDLOCAL
)
```

Below is an example of the filelist.txt

```
2174_1_1_TEST_|
2174_1_1_TEST_SO_|
2174_1_1_ABC_|
2174_1_1_ABC_DEF_|
2174_1_1_XYZ_MNO_|
998014_YOYO_SP_|
998014_YOYO_|
998014_MAILMAN_|
998014_BATMAN_|
998014_SPIDERMAN_|
998014_CATWOMAN_|
311009_SUPERMAN_|
```

And finally, here is a subset of the PDFs in the PDFCOMPARE folder:

```
2174_1_1_TEST_dev.pdf
2174_1_1_TEST_qa.pdf
2174_1_1_TEST_SO_dev.pdf
2174_1_1_TEST_SO_qa.pdf
```

The last suffix could change depending on which environment the PDF comes from, but it can only come from 4 at this point in time: dev, qa, uat, prod (if this info helps).

The program is having issues on this line:

```
SET COMPAREZIPS="dir /b "%%i*.pdf" | find /c "%%i" "
```

That line is always supposed to be 2, if indeed the program finds 2 similarly named files, but based on the example above it's finding 4 when it hits `2174_1_1_TEST_|` in filelist.txt and 2 when it hits `2174_1_1_TEST_SO_|` in filelist.txt.

If it helps, the issue only exists on the TEST/TEST_SO, ABC/ABC_DEF, YOYO/YOYO_SP files.

I've tried a multitude of things (changing the FOR loop, adjusting redirection/pipes, etc), but I keep coming back to scratching my head. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm defeated and asking for SO's help. Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `for` command to explicitly search what you need

```
SET "COMPAREZIPS=dir /b "%%idev.pdf" "%%iqa.pdf" "%%iuat.pdf" "%%iprod.pdf" ^| find /c "%%i" "
```

or add a filter to ensure that only the adecuated files are counted

```
SET "COMPAREZIPS=dir /b "%%i*.pdf" ^| findstr /i /r /c:"^%%i[^_]*\.pdf$" ^| find /c "%%i" "
```

This will solve the problem with the file count, but will not avoid the problem with the rest of the commands that are using `%%i*.pdf` to handle the files.

So, it is better to first retrieve the list of the files that will be handled in each iteration and then use this list to execute the rest of the commands

```
:ZIPPAIRS
::Zips pairs -- checks for pairs first using filelist.txt
ECHO [INFO] Checking for pairs, if a pair exists, zipping it up >> %LOG%
ECHO.
ECHO Zipping all pairs from your PDFCOMPARE folder...
ECHO.

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "sources=dev qa uat prod"
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
pushd "%DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE"
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN (filelist.txt) DO (
    :: Search for required files 
    dir /b "%%idev.pdf" "%%iqa.pdf" "%%iuat.pdf" "%%iprod.pdf" > "%tempFile%"
    for /f %%j in (
        ' ^<"%tempFile%" find /i /c "%%i" '
    ) do if %%j equ 2 (
        ECHO [INFO] Zipping %%i PDF's and control_file.xml >> %LOG%
        ECHO Zipping %%i PDF's and control_file.xml...
        %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\7-ZIP\7z a %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%i.zip @"%tempFile%" %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPAREDOWNLOADED\control_file.xml
        ECHO.
        ECHO [INFO] Moving %%i PDF's >> %LOG%
        ECHO Moving %%i PDF's
        ECHO.
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%k in ("%tempFile%") do MOVE %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%k %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\FINISHED
        MOVE %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%i*.zip %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\ZIPS
    ) else (
        ECHO.
        ECHO.
        ECHO [WARN] This compare %%i does not have a matching pair >> %LOG%
        ECHO This compare %%i does not have a matching pair
        ECHO.
        ECHO.
    )
)
popd
del /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul 
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! It worked, however on this line `for /f %%k in ("%tempFile%") do MOVE %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\%%k %DRIVE%\PDFCompareApp\PDFCOMPARE\FINISHED` it was not moving the files to the FINISHED directory :(. When I turned `ECHO ON` it kept saying file didn't exist (and the file was named really weird [like a temp file]).

Comment: @RichardS, Sorry, my fault. I forget to include the `for` command options. Answer corrected.